# Chinese linguistics: Could anyone give me pointers to the Traditional-Simplified Chinese translated corpora?

Tags: resource-request, chinese

I am a computational linguist and I need some datasets to evaluate my Simplified to Traditional Chinese converter.

Could anyone point to datasets which have pairs of Simplified-Traditional Chinese sentence translations?

Or stuff like translated books so that I curate my own datasets?

Comment: There is no strict thing called “Traditional Chinese”. What I mean by this is, there is “Simpified Chinese” and “Non-simplified Chinese”, and the most well known “non-simplified” orthographic standards are that by Taiwan and Hong Kong. Yes, Taiwan and Hong Kong actually have slightly different character choices when it comes to identical words. You need to specify whether you’re looking for the Taiwan standard or Hong Kong standard.

Comment: You can try Chinese Bible translations, they are lined by their chapters and verse numbers.